# How can we do traffic analysis for dashboards in Tableau Online without Site admin access?

Tags: tableau-api, dashboard, tableau-desktop

Need to create a dashboard reflecting the traffic on our existing dashboards on Tableau Online. Understand it can be done via Admin Insights, however, don't have site admin role access. Searching for a similar repository / meta data as available in Tableau Server via the dashboard traffic to views functionality

Answer (score 0):

The site admin can give you permissions to the TS Events data source, so you can build your own traffic reporting.